# Why can't I turn this Redis query result directly into a hash?

Tags: ruby, redis

This is confusing me to no end.  Why am I unable to perform this operation directly on the query?

```
(rdb:1) $redis.zrange(key(p_id, range), 0, -1, {withscores: true})
["2008", "15769"]

(rdb:1) Hash["2008", "15769"]
{"2008"=>"15769"}

(rdb:1) Hash($redis.zrange(key(p_id, range), 0, -1, {withscores: true}))
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `Hash' for Player:Module

(rdb:1) Hash[$redis.zrange(key(p_id, range), 0, -1, {withscores: true})]
{}
```

Comment: will the result always be a pair?

Comment: They will.. 4 more chars

Comment: ok, answer updated then, Hash[[pair]] is also possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should unpack the arguments:

```
Hash[*$redis.zrange(key(p_id, range), 0, -1, {withscores: true})]
```

`Hash#[]` takes also an array of pairs, so if the result is always a pair:

```
Hash[[$redis.zrange(key(p_id, range), 0, -1, {withscores: true})]]
```